# Xubuntu 20.10 has No Sound (Dummy Output) unless I reinstall pulseaudio after every reboot

Tags: pulseaudio

My Xubuntu 20.10 instsallation has No Sound (Dummy Output) unless I reinstall pulseaudio after every reboot.

How I re-install pulseaudio (obvious but just in case)

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall pulseaudio
```

I have tried just killing the pulseaudio service, and letting it restart on it's own.. It restarts, but no audio.  Reinstalling seems to do the trick though.

Has anyone seen this?

Update: I have submitted a bug report:
[Bug #1902580](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1902580)

Comment: can you show after a reboot when sound is not recognized `systemctl --user status pulseaudio.service` please.

Comment: Thanks: https://launchpadlibrarian.net/508917706/systemctl_--user_status_pulseaudio.service.txt

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from 20.4 to 20.10 and lost my line out built in audio. I reinstalled 5.6.17-050617 and booted from this instead of 5.8.26. Everything now works.

Comment: *"I reinstalled 5.6.17-050617 and booted from this instead of 5.8.26"*: What are you referring to?  How do you do this?  Please use [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1288971/edit) and make sure that your answer is complete.  I suggest that you add step-by-step instructions for us to follow.